# Coding utf-8 in Django template

Tags: django, templates, utf-8

I try use polish letters in my template index.html but I had an error

> utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 149: invalid start byte

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is your template file saved in UTF-8 or some other encoding?

Comment: If you are on Linux / Mac OS you can do `file /path/to/index.html` to find out if it was saved as UTF-8. It's most likely an issue with your editor.

Comment: Thank's i set it in PyCharm on encoding utf-8 like You said and it's work!